# Getting an empty graph while trying to plot an accuracy graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

So, when i try to plot a accuracy graph it shows an empty graph.

[image of graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UvRO.png)

```
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label='accuracy')
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], label='val_accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.ylim([0.5, 1])
plt.legend(loc='lower right')


test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=2)
print(test_acc)
```

the code of plotting the graph is this above and and my model is the code below

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))  # New convolutional layer
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
```

Also, I want to mention 1 important thing, as I am using free version of google colab, I can't use big datasets so I am using this code below to delete major part of my dataset so my colab doesn't crash

```
# Percentage of pictures to delete
percent_to_delete = 95

# Loop through all subdirectories (folders)
for foldername in os.listdir(dataDir):
    folder_path = os.path.join(dataDir, foldername)

    if os.path.isdir(folder_path):
        # List all files in the current folder
        files = os.listdir(folder_path)

        # Calculate the number of files to delete based on the percentage
        num_to_delete = int(len(files) * percent_to_delete / 100)

        # Randomly select files to delete
        files_to_delete = random.sample(files, num_to_delete)

        # Delete the selected files
        for filename in files_to_delete:
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
            os.remove(file_path)
```

Below is my model fitting code

```
lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate, decay_steps=10000, decay_rate=0.9)
optimizer = SGD(learning_rate=lr_schedule)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

#early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3, restore_best_weights=True)

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=30,
                    validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```